# How to get a video category with youtube api by the video ID

Tags: api, http, youtube

How to get a video category with youtube api by the video ID?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategoriespart=id&part=snippet&id=tjAsV8m24F4&key[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

i tried this but the result was :

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
  "etag": "qeAs28_qPv1tj8F0eBP7Qqr58Hw",
  "items": []
}
```

nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call :

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories

Give information about a specified VideoVategories than in this list :

```
2 - Autos & Vehicles
1 -  Film & Animation
10 - Music
15 - Pets & Animals
17 - Sports
18 - Short Movies
19 - Travel & Events
20 - Gaming
21 - Videoblogging
22 - People & Blogs
23 - Comedy
24 - Entertainment
25 - News & Politics
26 - Howto & Style
27 - Education
28 - Science & Technology
29 - Nonprofits & Activism
30 - Movies
31 - Anime/Animation
32 - Action/Adventure
33 - Classics
34 - Comedy
35 - Documentary
36 - Drama
37 - Family
38 - Foreign
39 - Horror
40 - Sci-Fi/Fantasy
41 - Thriller
42 - Shorts
43 - Shows
44 - Trailers
```

You need to do `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos`

Get the category ID and then call :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories
```

With the video category ID